# Duplex perception experiment - Can I try it on my own?

Tags: spoken-language, perception

I was reading about speech perception over headphones, “duplex perception” (Lieberman et al., 1981) — who note that when a speech stimulus was split into two parts and presented to different ears over headphones, the listeners hear one speech sound resulting from the integration across both ears as well as a non-speech sound.

Would love to try this out on my own. Are there stimuli online where I can play with this?